# Scribus PDF Form not working with adobe reader

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, pdf-form

I have created PDF Form using [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net)([Scribus Tutorial](https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Your_first_PDF_form_with_Scribus)). After filling form with **Adobe Reader** generated PDF label text get changed to some garbage value.

Please check screenshot for clear idea about issue.

1. **Before signing form**
   [image]
2. **After signing form**
   [image]

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: What version of Scribus are you using please to create this? And are you using Scribus plus some PDF-generator or the inbuilt PDF-Export from Scribus (and which settings / options do you use)?